# Bootstrap grid with varying width images

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I want to create a grid with 2 columns, the first of size col-md-1 and the second with width col-md-2.

In the 1st col i have 3 rows, each with a square image. The 2nd col has 2 rows, 1st with 1 image and 2nd with 2 images.

All images used are the ame dimensions originally.

This gives me below:
[image]

This causes me a slight issue - the gaps in the grid caused by 'col' class and the padding on the thumbnails means the bigger image is always either too big or small.

Has anybody acheived a acceptable way of acheiving this type of grid layout?

My code is as follows:

```
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2"> 
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <img src="img/home/photo_sq1.jpg" alt="image 1 missing" title="Image 1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <img src="img/home/photo_sq1.jpg" alt="image 1 missing" title="Image 1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <img src="img/home/photo_sq1.jpg" alt="image 1 missing" title="Image 1">
                        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">

                    <div class="col-md-12 col-padding">

                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="img/home/photo_sq1.jpg" alt="image 1 missing" title="Image 1">
                                </div>

                    </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">


                            <div class="thumbnail">
                              <img src="img/home/photo_sq1.jpg" alt="image 1 missing" title="Image 1">
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">


                            <div class="thumbnail">
                              <img src="img/home/photo_sq1.jpg" alt="image 1 missing" title="Image 1">
                            </div>


                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class with no padding to your css like this:

```
.no-padding {   
    padding: 0;
}
```

Then use this class on the div with:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-padding no-padding">
...
```

This should work.

You also need to add some more `margin-bottom` to the .`thumbnail` class.

```
.thumbnail {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

If needed you will want to adjust the padding using media queries.

Here is a [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x63jpLkj/)

Comment: Hi thx. I tried this before (should have mentioned) but i still get the issue of the fact that the 3 smaller images in col1 have more padding in total than the col2 as it only has 2 images from top to bottom.